# Regex to validate URL - Not checking for HTTP?

Tags: php, regex, url, validation

I know there are tonns of questions on here to validate a web address with something like this

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i
```

The only problem is, not everybody uses the `http://` or whatever comes before so i wanted to find a way to use the `preg_match()` but not checking for http as a **must have** but more of a doesn't really matter, i modified it to this but then it rejects the url it it **does** have `http://` in it:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i
```

I was hoping more to validate it on these conditions

- If it has http:// or www then just ignore this
- If the .extension is longer than 9 then reject
- If it contains **no** full stops

Anybody got an idea, thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> not everybody uses the http://

They should. Without a scheme it simply isn't a URL, and omitting it can cause weird problems. For example:

```
www.example.com:8080/file.txt
```

This is a valid URL with the non-existant scheme `www.example.com:`.

If you are sure that the normal scheme should be `http:`, you could try automatically appending `http://` to ‘fix up’ any URL that doesn't begin with `https?:`, before validation. But you shouldn't allow/keep/return schemeless URLs over the longer term.

Incidentally the current regex you are using is a long way from accurate according to the official URI syntax (see RFC 3986). It will disallow many valid URI characters, not to mention Unicode characters in IRI. If you want a proper validation you should use a real URL-parser; if you just want a quick check for obvious problems you should use something much more permissive. For example just checking for the absence of categorically-invalid characters like space and `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use the built in [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function?

```
filter_var('example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Not sure about the nine chars extension limit, but I guess you could easily check this in an additional step.

Comment: filter_var can be set up to filter and require the scheme or not (the http:// part, if you don't require it it will validate if you have it there or not). People love to reinvent the wheel. And they usually make it square.

Comment: @Erik. PHP seems to have removed FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED constant - at least it's no longer in the manual...

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a stage before the regexp to simply remove the `http://` if present ? The same would apply to the `www`. That may make your life a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(http\://|www\.)/

/^.+?\.\S{0,9}\./

/\./
```

Those should work for your bullet points?